# ng-model is undefined multiple ways can't get text from textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried a couple of ways, but I can't seem to read my ng-model. The alert always comes back as undefined:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pincode">Pin Code</label>
            <input type="email" style="width:550px" ng-model="pincode1" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Pin">
        </div>
         <a ng-click="adminCheck(pincode1)" style="width:550px" class="xpad btn btn-block btn-success">Login</a><br />
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.adminCheck = function(pin) {
    alert(pin);
    if ($scope.pincode1 == "4444") {
        alert("sorted");
    } else {
        $state.go($state.current.name, {}, {
            reload: true
        })
    }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
$scope.adminCheck = function(pin) {
    alert($scope.pincode1);
    if ($scope.pincode1 == "4444") {
        alert("sorted");
    } else {
        $state.go($state.current.name, {}, {
            reload: true
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using `type email` you need to put valid email address, the scope variable `(pincode1)` is not in the `scope` (`undefined`) **until u add a valid email address**

put valid email address like `xx@gmail.com`, and your code will work as expected.

---

To clarify more, simply put `{{ pincode1 }}` and check your input model value bind to here or not, you will see `{{ pincode1 }}` will prints nothing until you put a valid email address in the textbox.

---

here is the [demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3cGKTAXx1dcvKL33WmD1?p=preview) (check with valid and invalid email addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

check for the form validity before taking any actions - submitting, routing, etc

Change

```
<div class="form-group">
```

To

```
<form class="form-group"  name="myform">
```

(and close the corresponding tag properly)

In your controller, check for validity of the form. Here the form is valid only when the user inputs a valid email address

```
if($scope.myform.$valid){
//do your logic here
}
```